# Change background for login screen for 18.04

Tags: 18.04, login-screen, ubuntu-mate

I want to change the background for my login screen for 18.04.

I tried to change my login screen background via modifying /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css
but that file does not exist.

I found nothing using Appearance either.

Can the background be changed?

Comment: Assuming you're using Ubuntu MATE (as the question is tagged), this can be controlled via the "GTK+ Greeter Settings" found in your System menu 

Comment: @Matigo I tried GTK+ Greeter Settings". The background did not change.

Comment: It required a reboot to work.